# methods of propulsion of hydrogen plasma

Tags: acceleration

What would be the best method of accelerating a continuous flow of hydrogen plasma to 300 000 m/s.

I have thought about a rail gun approach but don't think this would be suitable for these speeds or a continuous flow.

The plasma can be flowing in anything.

Answer (score -2):

that is an extremely high speed. Is the plasma flowing in a pipe or vacuum system, or is it in some sort of containment vessel, which also has to be accelerated along with the plasma?

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.